# Pre-processing data before showing it in AdvancedDataGrid

Tags: apache-flex, flash, actionscript

I want to extend AdvancedDataGrid to show a [Waterfall Chart](http://www.ajaxperformance.com/wp-content/uploads/2006/12/two_conn_waterfall.png) in one of its columns.

To do that I already created custom cell render that shows bars as I need.

Now I have a little challenge: I have to pre-process data to show my Waterfall Chart properly. I have to do it before my grid is show. So, I assume that I have to extends AdvancedDataGrid and overwrite some methods.

Does anybody know where I have to start? Any examples?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I used wrong aproch. Instead, now I use creationComplete event to insert needed data.